# WCF error service error message with shared classes

Tags: c#, wcf, class, protobuf-net

Source code:
http://code.google.com/p/sevenupdate/source/browse/#hg/Source/SevenUpdate.Base

SevenUpdate.Base.Sui cannot be used since it does not match imported DataContract. Need to exclude this type from referenced types.

Now I tried unchecking reuse reference types and I was able to get my project to compile. but when sending a collection from the client it was never received or couldn't be deserialized on the server end.

I really need this to work. Any help would be appreciated, the fullsource code is provided by google code.

Comment: Anyone able to help me solve this? I am assuming it has to do with protobuf attributes being dropped. I been trying to figure out this error for weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt download the source and build it, but could it be that you are missing DataContract on this class? Sui class has a property of type Sua as DataMember so it will need to be serialized as well. It looks like this in your code currently

```
[ProtoContract, ]
[KnownType(typeof(ObservableCollection<LocaleString>))]
public class Sua
```

Comment: That missing datacontract was a simple error left when I did a search/replace to remove xml attributes, it was there prior. I fixed it and updated the service, error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

What would I need to do to reproduce this error? The first bit (about matching data-contract) sounds like WCF isn't very happy with you, which suggests you have two similar (but different) contracts "in play". If you are re-using the types from a shared library this shouldn't be a problem.

If you *do* end up excluding the types (and having a different model at the client and server) then it can get a *bit* tricker, since "mex" doesn't guarantee the positions will remain intact (and indde, they regularly change) - but you can fix this in a partial class, by using a few `[ProtoPartialMember(...)]` against the *type* (not pretty but it works).

But I stress - the main problem here seems to be WCF; if *that* isn't happy such that the code doesn't codegen / compile etc, then my hands are fairly tied (since it won't get as far as talking to protobuf-net).

Comment: The only thing would be to download the source, compile the base and admin projects, run the admin exe, I put it in a loop so it's easier to update the service while testing (it wont do anything except run in a loop on your machine). Then update the service for SevenUpdate, you will see the warning messages.

[code]void AddApp(Sua app);
void SetUpdates(Collection<Sui> appUpdates);
..etc[/code]

I started to get the errors. The classes are in SevenUpdate.Base which is shared. Could it be protobuf's attributes are being dropped by WCF causing the mismatch?

Comment: It was working fine, I am trying to send the classes to the service and the service returns results. (Duplex Contract), it may be that I just implemented it wrong. Prior to this, I was just serializing a temp file, and having the service deserialize it, something I want to avoid by using the WCF service I already have in place.